# Apps battery usage is high although no code is being execuded IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, background-process, battery

I have an IOS Chat Application that lets users chat with each other and lets users join a video call. Therefore the app has a lot of pods installed. My problem now is that whenever I launch the app the battery usage is immediately at the border of "high battery state" and "very high battery state" in the Xcode debugger. I also tried to just launch the app with nearly no code being execuded at all (just Firebase User LogIn), but the battery usage is still the same. Is there any solution to this?

A possible reason for this extreme high battery usage could be that because the app uses background modes to stay active in background when in a video call it also stays active in background when the user isn´t in a video call. Is it possible to define when the app should stay fully active in background and when it shouldn´t? And does the staying active in background actually influences the battery usage?

Comment: Better to put a screenshot of Xcode debugger.